# selenium filter out _blank, which opens new tab

Tags: python, selenium

I got some problems with selenium on python.

Currently, I am using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")` to get all web elements with an href. However, there are some hrefs with target=“_blank”, cousing selenum to open a new tab, which I dont want.

Is it possible to filter out those elements somehow?

Comment: can you share code lines please for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter them out by modifying your xpath, this should make it:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href and not(@target='_blank')]")
```

Good luck!